# Expose SOAP Service from SAP?

Tags: web-services, soap, abap, sap-r3

I've created a SOAP Service in ABAP, which perfectly works inside the network.
Now I wan't it to be called from outside and I haven't really found any tutorial.

Most likely a SAP Web Dispatcher or a reverse proxy is required, but how to use them?
Or is there an easier way to make the endpoint "public" and callable from the "outside"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it public not part of SAP system. You need to configure your network to allow incoming request. Generally you need to configure your firewall. You need to open a port on firewall and redirect it to your SAP server http/https port. It will also create a risk for opening http/https port to outside. You must sure about limit your your web service user authorizations and changing all default passwords and using update date SAP system for security patchs.

For more get security I prefer to use a proxy server like nginx/apache to just serve your SOAP service over it.

Comment: thank you - so you are saying that inside SAP, there is no possibility to make the server/soap-service accessible. Then I'll ask the network team

Comment: I try to said that there is no limitation in SAP for accepting incoming requests.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done thourgh reverse-proxies, to minimize risk of attacks from public Internet.

The general schema looks the same, although there are multiple variations depending on the company

[image]

The oldest and the most traditional reverse-proxy for SAP systems is a Web Dispatcher

[**SAP Web Dispatcher**](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73ehp1/7.31.19/en-US/48/8fe37933114e6fe10000000a421937/frameset.htm) it includes load balancing and HTTP filtering

https://informatik.rub.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/2_sap-secure-configuration.pdf

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SI/FAQ+Web+Dispatcher

https://blogs.sap.com/2021/05/09/landscape-architecture-sap-web-dispatcher-deployment/

[**SAP Gateway**](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw74/7.4.16/en-us/ec/aeea50ca692309e10000000a445394/content.htm?no_cache=true) is a framework for exposing functionality as REST/SOAP web-services

https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/15/sap-odata-service-get-consume-rest-service/

The tutorial for configuring **SAP Web Dispatcher + SAP Gateway** together

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/ec/342f1809c94d2b817ba772fe69e43f/content.htm?no_cache=true

The other options for reverse-proxy for SAP:

- **nginx**
- **Apache**
- ...

You are free to choose any reverse proxy on the market depending on your environment.

Comment: Thank you for this detailled answer - I'll check those sources to see what I can do!